# Functions with null derivative

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I am not here referring to [the devil staircase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), but to [the question mark function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function). This is a strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, with derivative always $0$. I have two questions:

1. Is this a surprising result (in the same way that continuous functions nowhere differentiable were thought surprising when discovered)?
2. What are the properties preventing this (obviously, we need a topological field to speak of derivative; are there exemples of connected topological fields with non constant functions having everywhere a null derivative?)

Comment: What is a "topological field" and why do we need it to speak of the derivative?

Comment: A topological field is a field with a topology such that the operations $x\mapsto -x$ $x,y\mapsto x+y$ $x,y\mapsto xy$ and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ are continuous. One will need a topology in order to take any sort of limit operation such as a derivative.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for the clarification!